# JObject toDictionary() using lambda only gives me values not the keys

Tags: c#, json, lambda, json.net

I'm trying to convert a JSON list of key value pairs stored in a JObject to a C# dictionary. I came really close but got stuck.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jContainer = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject();
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jCodes = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject();

jCodes.Add("UJ2W", "12345");
jCodes.Add("T62Q", "12346");
jCodes.Add("8I4D", "12347");
jCodes.Add("T45G", "12348");
jCodes.Add("Q91B", "12349");

jContainer.Add("codes", jCodes);
jContainer.Add("company", "Some Company");
jContainer.Add("log", "URL to logo");

Dictionary<string, string> dCodeTranslation = jContainer["codes"]
    .ToDictionary(k => (string)k, v => (string)v);
```

No matter which lambda code I use (I tried o, v and some other stuff) it keeps returning this dictionary:

```
12345 - 12345
12346 - 12346
12347 - 12347
12348 - 12348
12349 - 12349
```

instead of

```
UJ2W - 12345
T62Q - 12346
8I4D - 12347
T45G - 12348
Q91B - 12349
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting the items to `JProperty` enables you to retrieve their `Name` and `Value`:

```
var dCodeTranslation = jContainer["codes"].ToDictionary(
    k => { return ((JProperty)k).Name; }, 
    v => { return (string)((JProperty)v).Value; });

//output:
//UJ2W - 12345
//T62Q - 12346
//8I4D - 12347
//T45G - 12348
//Q91B - 12349
```

However you might want to think about `ToLookup` in case you might have several values for each key

Comment: Thank you very much! This solves my problem! In my case I know I will always get one value for each key, but thanks for the advice!